# How to check if PyObject* points to the type numpy.uint8

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-c-api

How do I use the Python C-API to check if a PyObject* points to the type numpy.uint8 etc?

(Note that I want to check if the PyObject* points to the type numpy.uint8, not if it points to an instance of the type numpy.uint8.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PyType_IsSubtype(child, parent)` to see if the child type inherits the parent, but it operates on `PyTypeObject*`, not `PyObject*`.

Comment: And how do I get the PyTypeObject* for numpy.uint8?

Comment: If you have an instance of numpy.uint8, you can access it via `object->ob_type`, but other than that, I don't know. I imagine you could get the `numpy` module it from the globals dict (via `PyEval_GetGlobals()`) and then access `numpy.uint8` from there, but I'm not sure on the exact method.